# input type radio buttons not changing despite user's interaction

Tags: php, html, radio-button

I have several tests. They are either in the enable position or disable position. So initially i am getting values from database and setting the attribute checked appropriately.

```
 if($lr['Test1']=="201")
    {
        echo "<tr><td>Test 1</td><td><input type='radio' name='Test1'  value='enable' > Enable <input type='radio' name='Test1' checked='checked' value='disable' > Disable </td> <td><input type='submit' name='Test' value='Submit'> </td></tr>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<tr><td>Test 1</td><td><input type='radio' checked='checked' name='Test1'  value='enable' > Enable <input type='radio'  name='Test1' value='disable' > Disable </td><td><input type='submit' name='Test' value='Submit'> </td></tr>";
    }
    if($lr['Test2']=="201")
    {
        echo "<tr><td>Test 2</td><td><input type='radio' name='Test2'  value='enable' > Enable <input type='radio' checked='checked' name='Test2' value='disable' > Disable </td><td><input type='submit' name='Test' value='Submit'> </td></tr>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<tr><td>Test 2</td><td><input  type='radio' checked='checked' name='Test2'  value='enable' > Enable <input type='radio'  name='Test2' value='disable' > Disable </td><td><input type='submit' name='Test' value='Submit'> </td></tr>";
    }
    if($lr['Test3']=="201")
    {
        echo "<tr><td>Test 3</td><td><input type='radio' name='Test3'  value='enable' > Enable <input type='radio' checked='checked' name='Test3' value='disable' > Disable </td><td><input type='submit' name='Test' value='Submit'> </td></tr>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<tr><td>Test 3</td><td><input checked='checked'  type='radio' name='Test3'  value='enable' > Enable <input type='radio' name='Test3' value='disable' > Disable </td><td><input type='submit' name='Test' value='Submit'> </td></tr>";
    }
    if($lr['Test4']=="201")
    {
        echo "<tr><td>Test 4</td><td><input type='radio' name='Test4'  value='enable' > Enable <input type='radio' checked='checked' name='Test4' value='disable' > Disable </td><td><input type='submit' name='Test' value='Submit'> </td></tr>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<tr><td>Test 4</td><td><input checked='checked' type='radio' name='Test4'  value='enable' > Enable <input type='radio'  name='Test4' value='disable' > Disable </td><td><input type='submit' name='Test' value='Submit'> </td></tr>";
    }
```

Everything is good. But even when the user changes a test from enable to disable, I am getting the same old value which is enable. i.e

```
$_POST['Test1'] is enable even when the user clicked disable radio button.
```

Please help me .

Comment: Looks to me like you want `<input type="checkbox">` - radio buttons are for allowing the user to choose between multiple values, checkboxes are for on/off scenarios.

Comment: It's difficult to tell exactly what is being generated.  Post the actual html for the generated form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I joined them in a form since they have different submit values and added method = get to see what it returned in the url! and it returned the right values..Try it this way maybe it will help

```
<form name="test" method="GET">
 <tr>
  <td>Test 1</td>
  <td><input type='radio' name='Test1'  value='enable' > Enable 
      <input type='radio' name='Test1' checked='checked' value='disable' > Disable 
  </td>
  <td><input type='submit' name='Test' value='Submit'> </td>
 </tr>
</form>
```